# SQLite Transaction fills a table BEFORE the transaction is committed

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a code that creates a datatable (in memory) from a select SQL statement. However I realised that this datatable is filling during the procedure rather as a result of the transaction comit statment, it does the job but its slow. What am I doing wrong ?

```
 Inalready.Clear() 'clears a dictionary
        Using connection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(conectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Dim sqliteTran As SQLite.SQLiteTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            Try
                oMainQueryR = "SELECT * FROM detailstable  Where name= :name AND Breed= :Breed"
                Dim cmdSQLite As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

                Dim oAdapter As New SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdSQLite)

                With cmdSQLite
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = oMainQueryR
                    .Parameters.Add(":name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    .Parameters.Add(":Breed", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                End With

                Dim c As Long = 0
                For Each row As DataRow In list.Rows 'this is the list with 500 names

                    If Inalready.ContainsKey(row.Item("name")) Then
                    Else
                        c = c + 1
                        Form1.TextBox1.Text = " Fill .... " & c
                        Application.DoEvents()

                        Inalready.Add(row.Item("name"), row.Item("Breed"))

                        cmdSQLite.Parameters(":name").Value = row.Item("name")
                        cmdSQLite.Parameters(":Breed").Value = row.Item("Breed")
                        oAdapter.Fill(newdetailstable)
                    End If

                Next

                oAdapter.FillSchema(newdetailstable, SchemaType.Source)


                Dim z = newdetailstable.Rows.Count
```

'At this point the newdetailstable is already filled up and I havent even committed the transaction

```
                '  sqliteTran.Commit()

            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Transactions protect against changes made by other users (i.e., connections); any changes made by your own application are immediately visible for itself.

Therefore, for in-memory databases, transactions are not useful unless you need rollbacks.

Comment: That's too bad, I didn't know that about SQLite transactions.  Plenty of use-cases for doing a batch of work where you'd want the traditional roll-back behavior if the whole batch could not succeed.

Comment: the data table is a vb.datatable not a database, simply the above code was/is ignoring the transaction and is processing each loop as a separate transaction imediately. Anyway I came here to delete the question as I used a different solution that is very fast. Simply I saved the names into a temp table using an insert transaction and then called a query that returns the desired information by using SQL statment Select  * FROM DetailsTable WHERE DetailsTable.name IN (Select TempIDs.Names from TempIDs) its fast and soleves the issue. Thank you for taking the time to answer.